# Visual Studio Web Developer Express 2012 RC: How to bookmark code?

Tags: visual-studio, ide, bookmarks, visual-studio-express

This used to be real easy in 2010, but now I can't even find the bookmarks window or the buttons to mark code. Renamed? moved?

This applies to the current 2012 beta. I could not find it in view->toolbars or view->other windows

**EDIT**: maybe I should have specified web developer express

[image]

[image]

this is not a duplicate of:
[Is there a way to bookmark code in a Visual Studio project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926046/is-there-a-way-to-bookmark-code-in-a-visual-studio-project)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you enabled expert settings before you tried this? If you go to Tools->Settings and then select 'Expert Settings' now it should show options that were hidden previously. See if this helps you out. (Now on 'View' tab there will be option shown for Bookmark Window.)
from:http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/Vsexpressvc/thread/a1264a2c-924a-4cf7-aa6c-eb2a7e5a29cb

Comment: durrrr. ok I always forget that it defaults to the basic settings. What always cracked me up is that line numbers used to only be part of the "expert" settings-- as if the non-expert would be better off just not knowing.

Comment: Heh, now it's the other way around.