# How can I change keyboard shortcut bindings in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Using Visual Studio Code what is the procedure to:

- Remap a built in command's keyboard shortcut. For example, say, Open File (default is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>, it's unlikely that anyone would actually change this, but the same process should probably apply for any built in shortcut).
- Remap an extension command's keyboard shortcut, say the Bookmark extension's toggle-bookmark (default <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>)

IN 2015, this involved editing configuration JSON files, but I don't know which one, or how.   In 2021 there's a new UI, how do I find it?

Answer (score 239, accepted):

Click File -> Preferences -> Keyboard shortcuts.  Use the tab that opens up to edit and find available key bindings and assign them.
[image: Screenshot of VS Code Keyboard Shortcuts window]

Open the `keybindings.json` file using the button in the tab-bar (screenshot below)

[image: button to open keyboards.json]

---

Historical Note: In very early versions of visual studio code, you would Click File -> Preferences -> Keyboard shortcuts and you would get JSON like this `keybindings.json`:

```json
// Place your key bindings in this file to overwrite the defaults
[
    { "key": "ctrl+o", "command": "workbench.action.files.openFile" },

    { "key": "ctrl+alt+k", "command": "bookmarks.toggle", "when": "editorTextFocus" }
]
```

Comment: For mac users click Code instead of File.

Comment: Is there an easy way to copy keyboard shortcuts from VS?

Comment: Click on {} icon next to the Split Editor Icon to open keybindings.json

Comment: For those of you looking for the `{}` it now looks like a document icon with an rounded arrow coming out of the left side. A shame their documentation fails to mention this.

Comment: This answer originally told you to edit some JSON, updated May 2021 to show the modern VS Code Keyboard Shortcuts UI.

Comment: For mac users: Click Code > Settings > KeyboardShortcuts

Answer (score 54):

If you want to change the advance settings of keyboard shortcut such as `when` then you can follow these steps:

**Update:**(Thanks @phdoerfler for pointing it out that icon has changed)

File->Preferences->Keyboard Shortcuts
Click on icon on top right corner that says "Open Keyboard Shortcuts(JSON)" to open JSON version and place the keybinding.

[image: Image showing icon]

You can find this in Documentation [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_advanced-customization).

Comment: The icon changed. It's no longer a {} but a page with an arrow pointing onto it. The tooltip reads "Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)". You can see it in the top right corner of this screenshot: https://code.visualstudio.com/assets/docs/getstarted/keybinding/open-keyboard-shortcuts-json.png

Comment: this only shows defaults, is the pattern really to edit defaults? I don't think it was before. Where is the custom keybindings.json stored? It is gone now.

Comment: @mathtick did you find the default keybindings.json? Cannot find it, only my own keybinding json.

Comment: @Timo I think I did by just searching. I have some keybindings.json file. The most confusing thing is that I think there are different locations that can get picked up ... and I was in some repo that had many copies of different keybindings.json.

Comment: The json file based editing method appears to be gone completely now in May 2021.

Answer (score 27):

The way to open the **JSON file** changed yet again in a recent version.

You need to click the middle of the three buttons in the tab bar.

[image]

You only need to do that if the change you need isn't possible on the normal settings screen.

Comment: This is still here in May 2021 but you can edit WHEN conditions without going in here.

Comment: Seems it has changed yet again and can't figure out where they've now hidden the only way to actually edit key bindings.

Answer (score 23):

## On Windows:

- go to **File -> Preferences -> Keyboard shortcuts**,
- or press **Ctrl+K, then Ctrl+S**,
- or edit `%UserProfile%\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\keybindings.json` file

## On Mac:

- go to **Code -> Preferences -> Keyboard shortcuts**,
- or press **Cmd+K, then Cmd+S**

**Keep in mind** you can type things like `shift ctrl c` in the Search input in Keyboard Shortcuts panel to find commands by their keybindings.

**[Here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings) you can find documentation** which among other stuff contains also information about what `When` conditions you can use.

Comment: the WHEN condition editing is now visually done. The JSON editing parts are probably no longer relevant.

Answer (score 6):

The latest version of Visual Studio Code 1.11.0 provides a rich and easy keyboard shortcuts editing experience using a new Keyboard Shortcuts editor. [Read more here on their website.](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_11#_keyboard-shortcuts-editor)

Comment: The "rich and easy" UI is hamstrung and does not allow many types of edits.

Comment: Update: In the latest version of VSCode on MAC, it's rather: **Code  -> Settings -> Keyboard shortcuts** or **Cmd+K, then Cmd+S** shortcut

Answer (score 6):

1. ctrl + shift + p
2. Type `open keyboard shortcut` in the search bar

> [image]

3. It opens keyboard Shortcuts. Here you can customize shortcuts.

(For extra info follow from 4th point)

4. There at the top right corner click on `open keyboard shortcuts (JSON)` (Refer to the image)

> [image: json icon]

5. There you can modify the key, command, and when. That is also cool.

I tried

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+a",
    "command": "workbench.action.terminal.selectAll",
    "when": "terminalFocus && !isMac"
}
```

by this now I can select all in vscode terminal

Answer (score 5):

FYI on mac the keybindings.json file sits there:

/Users/your_user_name/Library/Application Support/Code/User/keybindings.json

Answer (score 4):

I will not repeat others answers! And if like me! You get to install a mapping extension!

My prefered is [Visual studio keys map](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.vs-keybindings)

And the question would have been how you select it! How you change it ! Can we install multiples! And select between them!

First here some useful links about key binding and shortcuts

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/tips-and-tricks

And before any, know that you can get to the keymaps extension by using the bottom left settings button for settings context menu! As in the picture bellow:

[image]

or through `file>Preferences>keymap`

[image]

Then you have to install one of the keymaps

[image]

The thing to know is that **it will take place** and make the changes **right away**!

## What if you install another?

The new one take over! Or some mix! I couldn't tell!
And you may have problems!

## How you change from one to another?

Remove the old ! remove the new one! And install it again! That's the way that i found it works! Disabling and reenabling didn't work!

And better always let only one installed at a time!

Unfortunitly as by Now 2020-05-08 no options to select between keys mapping exist!

## Undo a keymap

Just remove! You may need to restart the editor!

## Restart the editor

Also note that if you uninstalled all and reinstalled the one you want! And changes didn't take place! **Close the editor and reopen it**! That's help!

I hope that's help and may be save you some searching time!

And sure in the future we will have better handling! As vscode is just keeping getting more awesome and awesome! So an option to select and better handling will is expected to be added! And we will wait for it!

Answer (score 1):

On Windows: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>, then <kbd>S</kbd>

On Mac: <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> then <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>

This opens Keyboard Shortcuts Editor. It's searchable/filterable by either shortcut name or the key combination itself (example: type "ctrl" to see all bindings to the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> key.)

Image:
[vscode search keyword shortcuts panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJrUT.png)

Answer (score 0):

To change keybord shortcut bindings in vs go to settings > Keyboard shortcuts

[image]

Then You will see this kind of page. In this red color box as I highlighted here you can insert the features such as delete, delete left these kind of activities you can search and then you can edit the keybindings as you wish.

[image]

also when you get your mouse pointer near some command it shows pen type icon to edit that specific key. Like this

[image]

Bu clicking that one you can add preferred key bindings as well like this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

On a Mac, if you prefer the same behavior for the home and end keys as in ubuntu, which is to go to the beginning or end of the line when these keys are pressed, edit your keybindings.json file like this

```
[
  {
    "key": "home",
    "command": "cursorLineStart",
    "when": "editorTextFocus"
  },
  {
    "key": "end",
    "command": "cursorLineEnd",
    "when": "editorTextFocus"
  },
]
```

Answer (score -1):

1. Open Key Shortcuts from Preferences -> Keyboard Shortcuts
2. Search for the action in search field
3. Right click on one of the results and select "Show same keybindings"
4. Delete the conflicting key binding!