# VS Code - Possible to switch tabs/files with cmd+numbers?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I started using Visual Studio Code today (I've been using Atom and Sublime for years).

In Atom/Sublime (and Chrome, Firefox, etc...) you can go to another open tab with CMD + a number. Is it possible to get that behavior in VSC? (Mac)

Right now "CMD + 2" just splits the file in two columns and I do not need that at all.

Answer (score 138, accepted):

**Yeah this is possible.**

**File -> Preferences -> Keyboard Shortcuts -> Click keybindings.json
[image: (document icon with an rounded arrow coming out of the left side)]**

```
{ "key": "cmd+1","command": "workbench.action.openEditorAtIndex1" },
{ "key": "cmd+2","command": "workbench.action.openEditorAtIndex2" },
{ "key": "cmd+3","command": "workbench.action.openEditorAtIndex3" },
{ "key": "cmd+4","command": "workbench.action.openEditorAtIndex4" },
{ "key": "cmd+5","command": "workbench.action.openEditorAtIndex5" },
{ "key": "cmd+6","command": "workbench.action.openEditorAtIndex6" },
{ "key": "cmd+7","command": "workbench.action.openEditorAtIndex7" },
{ "key": "cmd+8","command": "workbench.action.openEditorAtIndex8" },
{ "key": "cmd+9","command": "workbench.action.openEditorAtIndex9" }
```

Comment: Crazy that you have to do this, but it works like a charm. I added this right after my bindings for `{
        "key": "cmd+shift+[",
        "command": "workbench.action.previousEditor"
    },
    {
        "key": "cmd+shift+]",
        "command": "workbench.action.nextEditor"
    }, ...`

Comment: I changed `cmd+9` to `"command": "workbench.action.openLastEditorInGroup"`, so it opens the last tab open, just like in other applications on macOS

Comment: As of VSCode 1.25, the command `"workbench.action.openLastEditorInGroup"` changed to `"workbench.action.lastEditorInGroup"` per https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_25#_removed-commands

Comment: Works great. Note that "Click keybindings.json" is performed by clicking the **{}** button on the top right of the Keyboard Shortcuts title bar (for those not familiar with it, like me).

Comment: Now the feature that I want is these numbers to still work across panes. It seems that if you have two open panes, VScode has separate indexes for each pane.

Comment: In case people don't know: alt+1, alt+2, etc. has been in vscode for some time to switch between tabs.  But if you want to use cmd use the answer above.

Comment: "For those of you looking for the {} it now looks like a document icon with an rounded arrow coming out of the left side. A shame their documentation fails to mention this."  (From this comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33791097/how-can-i-change-keyboard-shortcut-bindings-in-visual-studio-code#comment101563575_33791170)

Comment: Ah yes, the "turn piece of paper over to see the JSON on the other side" icon.

Answer (score 7):

The answer from Ginfuru above still works fine, but if you want more things in VSC to behave like Atom, I can also recommend this extension: [Atom Keymap](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.atom-keybindings#overview),  that ports popular Atom keyboard shortcuts to VSC.

Answer (score 0):

My current config for choosing tab in mac VS Code:

```json
[
  {
    "key": "cmd+[",
    "command": "workbench.action.previousEditor"
  },
  {
    "key": "cmd+]",
    "command": "workbench.action.nextEditor"
  },
  {
    "key": "cmd+1",
    "command": "workbench.action.openEditorAtIndex1"
  },
  {
    "key": "cmd+2",
    "command": "workbench.action.openEditorAtIndex2"
  },
  {
    "key": "cmd+3",
    "command": "workbench.action.openEditorAtIndex3"
  },
  {
    "key": "cmd+4",
    "command": "workbench.action.openEditorAtIndex4"
  },
  {
    "key": "cmd+5",
    "command": "workbench.action.openEditorAtIndex5"
  },
  {
    "key": "cmd+6",
    "command": "workbench.action.openEditorAtIndex6"
  },
  {
    "key": "cmd+7",
    "command": "workbench.action.openEditorAtIndex7"
  },
  {
    "key": "cmd+8",
    "command": "workbench.action.openEditorAtIndex8"
  },
  {
    "key": "cmd+9",
    "command": "workbench.action.openEditorAtIndex9"
  },
  {
    "key": "cmd+0",
    "command": "workbench.action.lastEditorInGroup"
  }
]
```