# goto tab by number in VS Code on Mac doesn't work for first tab

Tags: visual-studio-code

how to change tabs by number in VS Code

- [Github issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/24753)
- [related Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41951206/visual-studio-code-go-to-a-tab-by-number)

on Mac, however, using `ctrl 1` doesn't navigate to first tab

have confirmed that `ctrl 1` preset is active on my local
[image]

curious if anyone else has run into this and, if so, how they resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An inelegant preliminary solution: switch shortcut to something else; I used Sublime's default keybinding for switching tabs based on numbered order, namely `CMD <#>`