# Align Visual Studio Code and Visual Studio Key Mappings

Tags: visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio-code

Is there an easy way to align the shortcut key mappings from Visual Studio with Visual Studio Code?

**Example**

Visual Studio auto-format document

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>

Visual Studio Code auto-format document

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> *I want to replace this with the above shortcut.*

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33791170/492258) may help

Comment: @moguzalp do you know if there are any JSON configs anywhere online that already have all of the mappings?

Comment: Or you can export your shortcuts with [this extention](https://github.com/madskristensen/ShortcutExporter) and convert json then apply to target

Comment: I want to do the opposite: use VSCode keys in VS, but no luck :/

Comment: @d.popov I have the same problem, I've been lookin for this for at least two yeas but apparently nobody else cares about this.. Default VS keybindings are terrible if you are used to vscode ones

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a Visual Studio Code extension called Visual Studio Keymap.

I haven't tried it myself but the example you gave is listed in the description.

Here is a link to it: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.vs-keybindings

Answer (score 0):

The code formatting is available in Visual Studio Code through the following shortcuts:

1. On Windows `Shift` + `Alt` + `F`.
2. On Mac `Shift` + `Option` + `F`.
3. On Ubuntu `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `I`.