# Disable editor selector dropdown / instant tab switching with CTRL + Tab

Tags: visual-studio-code

I find myself often CTRL + tabbing to a different editor and then directly using CTRL + shift + p to open the command selector. However if I don't release and re-press the CTRL key VSCode instantly switches from the file selector to the command selector. I never really liked the file selector dropdown anyways so how can I disable it?

I read something about Breadcrumbs but I think this is something different. So far I added these two to the settings.json:

```
"keybindings.json": [
  {
    "key": "ctrl+tab",
    "command": "workbench.action.nextEditorInGroup"
  },
  {
    "key": "ctrl+shift+tab",
    "command": "workbench.action.previousEditorInGroup"
  }
]
```

However they only fix the order in which tabs are switched.

Is there any way to remove the dropdown for CTRL + Tab completely? Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I'm basically trying to get rid of this dialog:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

To get the old behavour back where ctrl+tab/ctrl+shift+tab immediately switches to the next/previous tab without showing the popup, add the following to your `keybindings.json`:

```
// Place your key bindings in this file to overwrite the defaults
[
    { "key": "ctrl+tab",         "command": "workbench.action.nextEditor" },
    { "key": "ctrl+shift+tab",   "command": "workbench.action.previousEditor"}
]
```

Source: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/20295#issuecomment-285310413

Or use the "Keyboard Shortcuts editor". Under VSCode > File > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts.

More details here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings

Also helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33791170/1066234

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I follow your workflow but you can disable any keybinding, like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> for `Go To File...` ala `workbench.action.quickOpen` by rightclicking that command in the Keyboard Shortcuts file and select `Remove Keybinding`.  It would result in this in your keybindings.json:

```
{
  "key": "ctrl+p",
  "command": "-workbench.action.quickOpen"  // note the minus sign, that disables it
}
```