# Is it possible to change the behavior of Ctrl-K to Alt-Q or other key combination?(I am not asking about key bindigs but about key chords)

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio-code

Is it possible to change the behavior of `Ctrl+K` to `Alt+Q` or other key combination?
For example I want to use `Alt+Q` `W` or `Ctrl+I` `Q` instead of `Ctrl+K` `Q`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I change keyboard shortcut bindings in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33791097/how-can-i-change-keyboard-shortcut-bindings-in-visual-studio-code)

Comment: In key binding settings screen every key combo about chord start with ```Ctrl+K``` . So I think this is about Ctrl+K behaviour. But not. Simply set key combo ```Alt+A Q```. And also another ```Ctrl+P T```. All of them work.I found the clue in this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21035286/waiting-for-second-key-of-chord