# How to enable Shift+Delete in VS Code for Line Delition

Tags: visual-studio-code

I was **deleting a Line** just by pressing "Shift+Delete" keys in VS Code.

It's off for the last few days.

Can someone tell me how to enable it back.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: This question is already answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33791097/how-can-i-change-keyboard-shortcut-bindings-in-visual-studio-code

Comment: Many Thanks Abhay,

When I followed the instructions in my VS Code, the keyboard shortcuts was Ctrl+Shift+K

which was mapped on Shift+Del earlier.

I have changed back to Shift+Del and problem solved.