# How to apply bookmarks with a mouse click event on VisualStudioCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have Visual Studio Code(VSCode) 1.10.1 version installed on Windows 7. I am new to VSCode.

At the moment, if I click on the left side of a file before the line numbers, a red dot appears which is the breakpoint. But, how to replace breakpoint with bookmark instead? It does work with ctrl+alt+k. But, I prefer a mouse click to apply bookmarks.

I searched through the `settings.json` file. Couldn't find anything relevant to this.

Comment: any reason for doing this only from mouse?

Comment: 2023 and still waiting for setting a bookmark with a mouse click. It's quicker and intuitive.

Answer (score 2):

Press <kbd>F1</kbd> in VSCode, type `ext install` and then look for Bookmarks.

For details check this - [Are there bookmarks in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30179571/are-there-bookmarks-in-visual-studio-code)

Comment: I have installed bookmarks. It's in my extension. This extension allowed ctrl+alt+k.

Comment: any specific reason to do it only with mouse?

Comment: I find it much quicker than ctrl+alt+k

Comment: If this is the solution for you please mark it as answer.