# Visual Studio Code have Code Navigation in the same file like MVS?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I mean, in Visual Studio you can easily bookmark lines (default ctrl+k) and navigate foward/backward these marks, and also select to highlight the entire line bookmarked.

I use this a lot and is very handy, specially with very long files.

I simply can't find a similar feature in Visual Studio Code for this, there's nothing about that in the docs online, and I couldn't find anything on google or here.

So is this possible? How to do this:

. Bookmark lines highlightings the entire line

. Easy navigation between the Bookmarks foward/backward

thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are there bookmarks in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30179571/are-there-bookmarks-in-visual-studio-code)

Answer (score 1):

There's an [extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=alefragnani.Bookmarks) providing the requested feature.

see [this video](https://youtu.be/XHX-9Zhk0VI) for more details.

I also find [this website](https://vscodecandothat.com) very helful.