# is it able to navigate previous cursor in certain file in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm not gonna navigate the previous cursor (Ctrl + -). Instead, I need to navigate the previous cursor of a specific file. Imaging you may jumped from current file line 223 to another, then jump back to current file line 442. Then if we go back, it just go back to another file. What I need is go to current file line 223,.

Comment: You can use bookmarks [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30179571/are-there-bookmarks-in-visual-studio-code)

Answer (score 0):

From [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_navigation), those're all the navigation of VSCode. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> will help you navigating back. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> is just *Zoom Out*. From the example you give above, you need to **press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> 2 times**.