# CSS: Table of Contents with Jump to Links INSIDE the CSS Document itself

Tags: css, visual-studio-code

Im writing some CSS Code for my Website and the file is getting quite big so I'm wondering if there is any possibility (or a feature) inside of CSS to make a commented table of contents with line specification or even jump-to-links?

It would be so much easier to keep the overview while coding and find something faster to make changes.

BTW: Im writing in VSC, so if CSS doesn't offer such a feature, maybe VSC does?

Thanks for your time :)

Comment: have a look at the `OUTLINE` view in the Explorer tab

Comment: You could use the [bookmarks extension for VSCode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34048304/6831341), which might help.  Frankly, however, if your file is getting too long to navigate easily, you should probably consider breaking it into smaller, logically delineated files, that you then import into a single `index.css` (or perhaps compile into a single file at build time).