# Visual Studio Code: Is there a way to add "local comments" to code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, plugins, comments

Many times, while I am going through the code and I find the purpose of a block of code I feel the need to add a comment to save my "future me" to have to analyze that piece of code again.

Sometimes I cannot add the comment in the code as either the code is not mine or the comment is simply something that is not crystal clear to me but is obvious to the rest of the developers and the comment will not be admitted in the review.

I would like to know if there is a way to somehow add comments that would not modify the code source file itself but still be available next time I open the file.

I have tried to look for such an extension but with no success ... maybe it is just a corner case ..

Comment: there is an example extension **comments**, you can copy it to your extension folder to use

Comment: I'd just suggest keeping your own notes in separate "plaintext" / markdown files.

Comment: what would you expect / want to happen when you check out another branch? Perhaps one where many drastic changes have been made and git or whatever SCM you are using cannot track the diffs in the way that best represents what has happened?

Comment: Have a look at this thread:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30179571/are-bookmarks-supported-in-visual-studio-code