# Bookmarks in chrome devtools editor

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I use the Chrome DevTools to edit my large JavaScript file.

Is there a way to set Bookmarks in the code like in Visual Studio (see the hotkeys on https://stackoverflow.com/a/926065 or even better https://stackoverflow.com/a/38419034)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interesting! No, DevTools doesn't have official support for this one. I filed a feature request: https://crbug.com/963682

## Update

We don't have official support for this feature, but there is a workaround.

1. Use a [line-of-code breakpoint](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/breakpoints#loc) as your "bookmark".
2. Disable that breakpoint from the **Breakpoints** pane.
3. Click the preview to jump to that line of code.

[image: bookmarks]

P.S. I [tweeted](https://twitter.com/kaycebasques/status/1128819731018838016?s=20) this workaround idea. Thank you for the inspiration.

Comment: Would you be aware if something like this is capable in the Elements tab?